# How to set repeated of repeated elements in proto3

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, protobuf-c

I'm having these two definitions in my .proto:

```
// all the shards on a server
message ConfigEntry {
  repeated Shard shards = 2;
  string server = 3;
}

// information on all the groups
message QueryResponse {
  repeated ConfigEntry config = 1;
}
```

And in my c++ file, I have this map that I'm trying to set in QueryResponse:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<shard_t>> servers;
```

I can't find any way to set the values in my map to config in QueryResponse, any ideas how to do this?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
    for (auto const &item : servers)
  {
    auto c = response->add_config();
    c->set_server(item.first);
    for (auto s : item.second)
    {
      Shard *sh = c->add_shards();
      sh->set_lower(s.lower);
      sh->set_upper(s.upper);
    }
  }
```

we call add_config() to get a ConfigEntry that we will set its server name, and then loop through the vector and add each shard separately.